# Can't get javascript to work from external file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a table of functions that does simple things like find the factorial of a number and such. I created the HTML for this table but I can't seem to get the javascript to work so that it'll pop out the correct calculations for the functions on the table.

Here is the HTML and javascript:

https://jsfiddle.net/qizzle/L4se9nvz/

```
function calculatefactorial(number){
    function factorial(num)
    {
                if(num <= 1)
                    return 1;

                return num * factorial(num - 1);
    }
    document.factorials.factorialsfield.value = factorial(number);
}
```

When I enter a number into the factorials box and click calculate it is suppose to replace the input number and return the result. What am I doing incorrectly and any suggestions on how to better implement this tasks?

Comment: If the problem is with loading JS from an external file, then you'll have to show us the HTML where you try to load it and where you try to call it. Linking to a JSFiddle does not good since (a) it makes the question dependant on an external site (and is therefore off-topic) and (b) it doesn't show us the problem because the JS isn't in an external file.

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 errors in your fiddle:

- the javascript code gets loaded onLoad, you should load it in your head instead
- the variable you pass to your `calculatefactorial` function has a typo, use `factorialsfield` instead of `factorialfield` (wih an 's'):

  calculatefactorial(factorialsfield.value)

https://jsfiddle.net/L4se9nvz/1/